# Relationship between Schur vectors and eigen vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}$ has distinct eigenvalues and $AB = BA$ what can I say about the Schur vectors of $B$?

I can see that $A,B$ share eigen vectors but this doesn't say anything about Schur vectors of B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ be a basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$ formed by eigenvectors of A associated to $a_1,\ldots,a_n$. Notice that they are also eigenvectors of $B$.
Therefore $V_k=\operatorname{span}\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ is left invariant by $B$.

Let $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ be an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$ obtained by the Gram-Schmidt process on $v_1,\ldots,v_n$.

Notice that $V_k=\operatorname{span}\{w_1,\ldots,w_k\}$.

Since $B(V_k)\subset V_k$, for $1\leq k\leq n$, then $B=ZTZ^*$, where $Z$ is the unitary matrix with columns $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ and $T$ is a triangular matrix.

So the schur vectors are $w_1,\ldots,w_n$.

Comment: How did you go from $B(V_k) \subset V_k$ to the Schur decomposition? I can't follow that. Presumably then $w_1,w_2,\cdots,w_n$ are Schur vectors of A as well?

Comment: Hi @SrinivasEswar. Since $B(V_j)\subset V_j$, for $1\leq j\leq n$, then $Bw_j=\sum_{i=1}^jt_{ij}w_i$. So the matrix $B$ on the basis $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ is $Z^*BZ=(t_{ij})$. Notice that in this sum, $\sum_{i=1}^jt_{ij}w_i$, $i$ is varying from $1$ to $j$. So if $i>j$ $t_{ij}=0$. Thus, $Z^*BZ$ is upper triangular. You are right, these are also the Schur vectors of $A$.

Comment: Ah, yes I can see this now. The summation representation really helps. Thanks!